# Interconnected DNS Information

Tags: dns

One of the methods to verify if a domain is legitimate or not is to check out its DNS records and their interconnection. The ones I could find are.

1. NS and PTR record
2. A and AAAA pointing to same address (so that the same website is served) etc.

There may be more.

Are there any other DNS records that are interrelated and the existence of one implies/is required for the other in order to function legitimately?

Comment: How can A and AAAA can point to the same address if one is IPv4 and the other IPv6? You might try to check if they point to the same system but it might be hard to find out if the endpoint is really the same system. Also, there might be no PTR records. Apart from that, what you consider a "legitimate" domain in the first place?  If you care about the domain not serving malicious content then you don't see this from DNS. If you care only about DNS records being complete and making sense then this is off-topic since not about security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DNSSEC - Domain Name System Security Extensions**

- It is a set of extensions to DNS which provide to DNS clients
  (resolvers) origin authentication of DNS data, authenticated denial
  of existence, and data integrity, but not availability or
  confidentiality.
- It adds a layer of trust on top of DNS by providing authentication.

When a DNS resolver is looking for security.stackexchange.com, the .com nameservers help the resolver verify the records returned for stackexchange, and stackexchange helps verify the records returned for security. The root DNS name servers help verify .com, and information published by the root is vetted by a thorough security procedure, including the Root Signing Ceremony.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System_Security_Extensions